# Query all images with certain tag in media library using visual portfolio plugin

Tags: custom-taxonomy, images, media-library

**Introduction:**

I am developing a wordpress website and want to use the Visual Portfolio plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-portfolio/). This plugin gives me the ability to display a gallery of posts. It also gives me the ability query my posts with a custom *query string*:

[image: field in the visual portfolio plugin where I add in a custom query]

**What I want to do:**

I want the visual portfolio plugin to query all images in my media library with the category `gallery`.

**What I have done:**

I have used the F4 Media Taxonomies plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/f4-media-taxonomies/) to give categories to my images. According to that plugin's directions, I have added the following code to my `functions.php` to enable the taxonomy `category`:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'attachment');
});
```

Next, on the page where I create my Visual Portfolio gallery (screenshot above), I add in the following query string:

```
post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_status=inherit&tax_query[0]taxonomy=category&tax_query[1]term=gallery&tax_query[2]field=slug
```

**What happens:**

The Visual Portfolio plugin simply displays all the images in my media library, not just images with category `gallery`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Instead of `term=gallery` try `category=gallery`

Comment: This gives me the same result; the plugin displays all the images in my media library.